# An extreme point that is not strongly exposed

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to construct an example that a point is extreme but is not exposed.
This example can be in the following :

> A compact convex subset $K‎\subset‎\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and a point $u\in K$ such that $u$ is an extreme point of $K$, but is not an exposed point of $K$.

Also,

> Every denting point is extreme and strongly exposed point.

I want to understand these proofs.

Comment: See Example 8.4 [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.caltech.edu%2Fsimon_chp8.pdf&ei=w7kEU_jAMqS6yAG36ICADg&usg=AFQjCNEx2fBv_qfDg8T7uiF3w6CA7HxwKA&bvm=bv.61535280,d.aWc&cad=rja).

Comment: Ok,thanks.But latter..